# Change FontAwesomeIcon when state updated (React.JS)

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, sidebar

I added a sidebar which slide out from the application. I want to change the button of sidebar  **from A icon to B icon** as the sidebar slides out. What I cannot figure it out is that how I can change the state of Fontawesome code?

I want to change A icon (`<i className=" fa fa-
reply fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>`) to B icon (`<i className="fa fa-share fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>` )

A part of my code is as bellow.

```
class Category extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    })
    console.log(!this.state.isOpen)
  }
  render() {
    const categoryStatus = this.state.isOpen ? "isopen" : "";
    const categoryContainer = this.state.isOpen ? "isopen" : "";
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="categoryContainer">
          <div className={categoryContainer}>
            <h3 >CATEGORIES</h3>
          </div>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <i className="slideinButton fa fa-reply fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className={categoryStatus} id="category">
          <input className="categoryInput" type="text" value="Add Category" placeholder="Add Category" />
          <ul>
            <li>Greetings</li>
            <li>Main Switchboard</li>
            <li>Interjections</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and add proper indentations. This is really hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a state variable controlling the slider, you can use that to determine what icon should be shown. Just add a condition that returns the proper one depending on that state:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>
  <i className={"slideinButton fa fa-" + (this.state.isOpen ? "share" : "reply") + " fa-2x"} aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

alternatively, if you find this more readable:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>
  {this.state.isOpen
    ? <i className="slideinButton fa fa-share fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    : <i className="slideinButton fa fa-reply fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  }
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I will pay more attention for putting my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same as you did for `categoryStatus` and `categoryContainer`.

```
const icon = this.state.isOpen ? 'reply' : 'share'

<button onClick={this.handleClick}>
  <i className={`slideinButton fa fa-${icon} fa-2x`} aria-hidden="true" />
</button>
```

Even better approach would be to create an `Icon` component where you can send the `icon` prop to it (as `reply`, `share`..) so you can reuse the same Icon component in different places of your code. Not to mention that you write less code with it.